# HTML video player (Fluid Player) playing more then one video

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to use Fluid  PLayer in my HTML site on multiple videos. But I must be doing something wrong because only first one is playing in Fluid Player. I think that there is something wrong in giving all  tags same id but i'm not sure. Any help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v2/current/fluidplayer.min.css" type="text/css"/>
 <script src="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v2/current/fluidplayer.min.js"></script>
 <video id="short" height="225" loop  controls> 
     <source src="wrestling.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
 </video>
 <video id="short" height="225" loop  controls> 
     <source src="wrestling.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
 </video>
 <video id="short" height="225" loop  controls> 
     <source src="wrestling.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
 </video>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myFP = fluidPlayer(
        'short',
        {
            layoutControls: {
    fillToContainer: false,
    primaryColor: false,
    posterImage: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    playButtonShowing: true,
    playPauseAnimation: true,
    mute: false,
    logo: {
      imageUrl: null,
      position: 'top left',
      clickUrl: null,
      opacity: 1,
      mouseOverImageUrl: null,
      imageMargin: '2px',
      hideWithControls: false,
      showOverAds: false
    },
    htmlOnPauseBlock: {
      html: null,
      height: null,
      width: null
    },
    allowDownload: false,
    allowTheatre: false,
    playbackRateEnabled: false,
    controlBar: {
      autoHide: true,
      autoHideTimeout: 1,
      animated: false
    },
            },
            vastOptions: {
            }
        }
    );
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong in giving all tags same id.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v2/current/fluidplayer.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v2/current/fluidplayer.min.js"></script>
    <video id="short" height="225" loop  controls> 
            <source src="wrestling.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
    <video id="short" height="225" loop  controls> 
            <source src="wrestling.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
    <video id="short" height="225" loop  controls> 
            <source src="wrestling.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var myFP = fluidPlayer(
        'short',
        {
            layoutControls: {
    fillToContainer: false,
    primaryColor: false,
    posterImage: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    playButtonShowing: true,
    playPauseAnimation: true,
    mute: false,
    logo: {
      imageUrl: null,
      position: 'top left',
      clickUrl: null,
      opacity: 1,
      mouseOverImageUrl: null,
      imageMargin: '2px',
      hideWithControls: false,
      showOverAds: false
    },
    htmlOnPauseBlock: {
      html: null,
      height: null,
      width: null
    },
    allowDownload: false,
    allowTheatre: false,
    playbackRateEnabled: false,
    controlBar: {
      autoHide: true,
      autoHideTimeout: 1,
      animated: false
    },
            },
            vastOptions: {
            }
        }
    );
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing the same id 'short' for all the 3 video tags and invoking single fluidplayer instance

providing modification to the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v2/current/fluidplayer.min.css" type="text/css"/>
 <script src="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v2/current/fluidplayer.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Providing unique id for each element -->
 <video id="short1" height="225" loop  controls> 
     <source src="wrestling.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
 </video>
    <!-- Providing unique id for each element -->
 <video id="short2" height="225" loop  controls> 
     <source src="wrestling.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
 </video>
    <!-- Providing unique id for each element -->
 <video id="short3" height="225" loop  controls> 
     <source src="wrestling.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
 </video>

</body>

<!-- INVOKING FIRST PLAYER -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myFP = fluidPlayer(
        'short1',
        {
            layoutControls: {
    fillToContainer: false,
    primaryColor: false,
    posterImage: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    playButtonShowing: true,
    playPauseAnimation: true,
    mute: false,
    logo: {
      imageUrl: null,
      position: 'top left',
      clickUrl: null,
      opacity: 1,
      mouseOverImageUrl: null,
      imageMargin: '2px',
      hideWithControls: false,
      showOverAds: false
    },
    htmlOnPauseBlock: {
      html: null,
      height: null,
      width: null
    },
    allowDownload: false,
    allowTheatre: false,
    playbackRateEnabled: false,
    controlBar: {
      autoHide: true,
      autoHideTimeout: 1,
      animated: false
    },
            },
            vastOptions: {
            }
        }
    );
</script>
<!-- INVOKING SECOND PLAYER -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myFP = fluidPlayer(
        'short2',
        {
            layoutControls: {
    fillToContainer: false,
    primaryColor: false,
    posterImage: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    playButtonShowing: true,
    playPauseAnimation: true,
    mute: false,
    logo: {
      imageUrl: null,
      position: 'top left',
      clickUrl: null,
      opacity: 1,
      mouseOverImageUrl: null,
      imageMargin: '2px',
      hideWithControls: false,
      showOverAds: false
    },
    htmlOnPauseBlock: {
      html: null,
      height: null,
      width: null
    },
    allowDownload: false,
    allowTheatre: false,
    playbackRateEnabled: false,
    controlBar: {
      autoHide: true,
      autoHideTimeout: 1,
      animated: false
    },
            },
            vastOptions: {
            }
        }
    );
</script>
<!-- INVOKING THIRD PLAYER -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myFP = fluidPlayer(
        'short3',
        {
            layoutControls: {
    fillToContainer: false,
    primaryColor: false,
    posterImage: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    playButtonShowing: true,
    playPauseAnimation: true,
    mute: false,
    logo: {
      imageUrl: null,
      position: 'top left',
      clickUrl: null,
      opacity: 1,
      mouseOverImageUrl: null,
      imageMargin: '2px',
      hideWithControls: false,
      showOverAds: false
    },
    htmlOnPauseBlock: {
      html: null,
      height: null,
      width: null
    },
    allowDownload: false,
    allowTheatre: false,
    playbackRateEnabled: false,
    controlBar: {
      autoHide: true,
      autoHideTimeout: 1,
      animated: false
    },
            },
            vastOptions: {
            }
        }
    );
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v2/current/fluidplayer.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v2/current/fluidplayer.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Providing unique id for each element -->
    <video id="short1" height="225" loop  controls> 
            <source src="wrestling.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
    <!-- Providing unique id for each element -->
    <video id="short2" height="225" loop  controls> 
            <source src="wrestling.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
    <!-- Providing unique id for each element -->
    <video id="short3" height="225" loop  controls> 
            <source src="wrestling.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>

</body>

<!-- INVOKING FIRST PLAYER -->
<script type="text/javascript">
     var myFP = fluidPlayer(
        'short1',
        {
            layoutControls: {
    fillToContainer: false,
    primaryColor: false,
    posterImage: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    playButtonShowing: true,
    playPauseAnimation: true,
    mute: false,
    logo: {
      imageUrl: null,
      position: 'top left',
      clickUrl: null,
      opacity: 1,
      mouseOverImageUrl: null,
      imageMargin: '2px',
      hideWithControls: false,
      showOverAds: false
    },
    htmlOnPauseBlock: {
      html: null,
      height: null,
      width: null
    },
    allowDownload: false,
    allowTheatre: false,
    playbackRateEnabled: false,
    controlBar: {
      autoHide: true,
      autoHideTimeout: 1,
      animated: false
    },
            },
            vastOptions: {
            }
        }
    );
</script>
<!-- INVOKING SECOND PLAYER -->
<script type="text/javascript">
     var myFP = fluidPlayer(
        'short2',
        {
            layoutControls: {
    fillToContainer: false,
    primaryColor: false,
    posterImage: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    playButtonShowing: true,
    playPauseAnimation: true,
    mute: false,
    logo: {
      imageUrl: null,
      position: 'top left',
      clickUrl: null,
      opacity: 1,
      mouseOverImageUrl: null,
      imageMargin: '2px',
      hideWithControls: false,
      showOverAds: false
    },
    htmlOnPauseBlock: {
      html: null,
      height: null,
      width: null
    },
    allowDownload: false,
    allowTheatre: false,
    playbackRateEnabled: false,
    controlBar: {
      autoHide: true,
      autoHideTimeout: 1,
      animated: false
    },
            },
            vastOptions: {
            }
        }
    );
</script>
<!-- INVOKING THIRD PLAYER -->
<script type="text/javascript">
     var myFP = fluidPlayer(
        'short3',
        {
            layoutControls: {
    fillToContainer: false,
    primaryColor: false,
    posterImage: false,
    autoPlay: false,
    playButtonShowing: true,
    playPauseAnimation: true,
    mute: false,
    logo: {
      imageUrl: null,
      position: 'top left',
      clickUrl: null,
      opacity: 1,
      mouseOverImageUrl: null,
      imageMargin: '2px',
      hideWithControls: false,
      showOverAds: false
    },
    htmlOnPauseBlock: {
      html: null,
      height: null,
      width: null
    },
    allowDownload: false,
    allowTheatre: false,
    playbackRateEnabled: false,
    controlBar: {
      autoHide: true,
      autoHideTimeout: 1,
      animated: false
    },
            },
            vastOptions: {
            }
        }
    );
</script>
</html>
```